# ggplot2 histogram color not bleeding through

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, overlay

I'm trying to plot an overlaid histogram using `position = 'identity'`. It usually works fine, but this time the other color is not bleeding through. Depending on color assignments, one of the colors dominates and doesn't allow the other to bleed through when there is overlap. The other color only shows where there is no overlap. The dataset is the same as others used previously (same data types) except that it has come from an SPSS .sav file. Any chance that is the problem?

Here's what I want:  [image]

This is what I'm getting: [image]

Tried factoring variables, has no effect.

```
ggplot(spvdata, aes(AGE, fill = GENDER)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2, alpha = .9, position = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = twocolorPalette,
                    labels = c("Female", "Male")) +
  labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Number of patients")
```

The structure for `spvdata` is `(*, "format.spss")= chr "A30"`

I expect to get the same plot as previously. But there seems to be something different about the data.

[image: small dataset with alpha = 0.9]

The MALE entries are blocking the FEMALE. Why is it not the same as the first plot?

Comment: Did you use a lower `alpha` value for previous use cases? `alpha = .9` may be too high for a second colour to show through.

Comment: Yes, I've tried varying the alpha. What I want is the plot above, which was created with the same code (above) from a different dataset. I tried to make a small repo:

Comment: dbl_var <- c(56, 52, 56, 54, 52, 52, 52, 54)
chr_var <- c("MALE", "MALE", "MALE", "MALE","FEMALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE")
testd <- data.frame(dbl_var, chr_var)
testd
ggplot(testd, aes(dbl_var, fill=chr_var)) + 
        geom_histogram(binwidth=2, alpha=.3, position="identity")

Comment: The colours do bleed through. That's why you get different shades of bluish-green in the chart. But if you want one colour above another (as per the first chart), it should be `position = "stack"` rather than `position = "identity"`.